# Inconsistent results between nodetool status and netstats

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm running a production cluster of `cassandra 3.11.4` and, after replacing a dead node I see inconsistent results running `nodetool status` on the nodes of the cluster.

From the node I just rerolled if I see the node is in `Mode: JOINING` when running `nodetool netstats` but `NORMAL` when running `nodetool status`

```sh
$ nodetool status
Datacenter: analytics
=========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  MY.NODE.248.75   99.89 GiB  256          54.4%             bf95b6e6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0bdcea1143c2  zone3
UN  xx.xx.248.74   364.8 GiB  256          46.5%             a69ac515-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-a273641bf5ed  zone2
UN  xx.xx.248.76   379.31 GiB  256          46.8%             69d230ae-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4cd9a5f808a4  zone1
UN  xx.xx.248.95   418.66 GiB  256          53.2%             b8087d37-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c182049b8229  zone1
UN  xx.xx.248.96   405.81 GiB  256          53.5%             8d23ceed-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-3a3141147488  zone2
UN  xx.xx.248.131  354.7 GiB  256          45.6%             4df1c02f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-bdf3ddacefbb  zone3
```

```sh
$ nodetool netstats
Mode: JOINING
Bootstrap a2778da0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-27852729bf78
    /xx.xx.248.95
        Receiving 475 files, 98682840459 bytes total. Already received 14 files, 2982307838 bytes total
            ------------/--------------- 5123303/5123303 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.95
            ------------/--------------- 765/765 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.95
            ------------/--------------- 162558297/162558297 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.95
            ------------/--------------- 3434358/3434358 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.95
            ------------/--------------- 51171126/51171126 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.95
            ------------/--------------- 18640569/18640569 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.95
            ------------/--------------- 29418262/29418262 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.95
            ------------/--------------- 1194322/1194322 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.95
            ------------/--------------- 2250914/2250914 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.95
            ------------/--------------- 129426329/129426329 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.95
            ------------/--------------- 14247176/14247176 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.95
            ------------/--------------- 5032/5032 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.95
            ------------/--------------- 2493672813/3000317114 bytes(83%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.95
            ------------/--------------- 53086217/53086217 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.95
            ------------/--------------- 18078355/18078355 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.95
    /xx.xx.248.74
        Receiving 409 files, 165242387363 bytes total. Already received 13 files, 10834692880 bytes total
            ------------/--------------- 1446536/1446536 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.74
            ------------/--------------- 513/513 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.74
            ------------/--------------- 19595017/19595017 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.74
            ------------/--------------- 3779588/3779588 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.74
            ------------/--------------- 105726592/105726592 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.74
            ------------/--------------- 144239413/144239413 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.74
            ------------/--------------- 1319826/1319826 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.74
            ------------/--------------- 92150515/92150515 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.74
            ------------/--------------- 36223706/36223706 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.74
            ------------/--------------- 9908623667/9908623667 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.74
            ------------/--------------- 125799091/125799091 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.74
            ------------/--------------- 203425367/396431426 bytes(51%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.74
            ------------/--------------- 320065/320065 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.74
            ------------/--------------- 192042984/192042984 bytes(100%) received from idx:0/xx.xx.248.74
    /xx.xx.248.76
Read Repair Statistics:
Attempted: 0
Mismatch (Blocking): 0
Mismatch (Background): 0
Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Dropped
Large messages                  n/a         0              0         0
Small messages                  n/a         0             35         0
Gossip messages                 n/a         0          26720         0
```

Also, if I run `nodetool status` from another node of the cluster the rerolled node is marked as `DN`.

```sh
$ nodetool status
Datacenter: analytics
=========================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
DN  MY.NODE.248.75   99.89 GiB  256          54.4%             bf95b6e6-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-0bdcea1143c2  zone3
UN  xx.xx.248.74   364.78 GiB  256          46.5%             a69ac515-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-a273641bf5ed  zone2
UN  xx.xx.248.76   379.31 GiB  256          46.8%             69d230ae-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-4cd9a5f808a4  zone1
UN  xx.xx.248.95   418.66 GiB  256          53.2%             b8087d37-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-c182049b8229  zone1
UN  xx.xx.248.96   405.81 GiB  256          53.5%             8d23ceed-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-3a3141147488  zone2
UN  xx.xx.248.131  354.7 GiB  256          45.6%             4df1c02f-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-bdf3ddacefbb  zone3
```

Comment: After the time needed to move the data around the cluster now `nodetool status` shows consistent results on all nodes